# Loop of findOne in mongoose issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, mongoose

I'm having trouble with a loop of mongoose findOne.

I have an array of ObjectID, and I need to get another value of the document (the value keyword)
This is what I have so far:

```js
 
let qarray = []
  

   for (var i = 0; i < req.body.keyword.length; i++) {
     let pushy = db.collection('keywords').findOne({ "_id": req.body.keyword[i]})
    qarray.push(pushy.keyword)
    console.log(pushy); // for debugging purpose
    console.log(req.body.keyword[i]); // for debugging purpose
   }
   console.log(qarray);
```

that the result:

```
Promise { <pending> }
60ab81c5be36d74968e23d14
Promise { <pending> }
60a77893b015d85f38a3323f
[ undefined, undefined ]
```

**EDIT**

I went with the loop solution, but I'm not very familiar with asynchronous functions...

```js
async function fetchSomeStuff(expTemp){
let qarray = []
for (var i = 0; i < expTemp.keywordid.length; i++) {
  console.log(expTemp.keywordid);
  console.log(db.collection('keywords').findOne({ _id: expTemp.keywordid[i]}));
  let pushy = await db.collection('keywords').findOne({ _id: expTemp.keywordid[i]})
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
  .then(qarray.push(pushy.keyword))
}
console.log(qarray);
}
```

This gives me theses problems messages :

*Promise '{ pending }'*

*ReferenceError: Cannot access 'pushy' before initialization*

I guess that I've to wait for the the db to fetch then put in into my array, and I'm surely missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $in instead

```
async function fetchSomeStuff(){
  const pushy = await db.collection('keywords').find({"_id" : { $in : req.body.keyword}});
  return pushy;
}
```

Or if you still want to loop and use findOne()

```
async function fetchSomeStuff(){
  let qarray = []
  

  for (var i = 0; i < req.body.keyword.length; i++) {
    let pushy = await db.collection('keywords').findOne({ "_id": req.body.keyword[i]})
    qarray.push(pushy.keyword)
    console.log(pushy); // for debugging purpose
    console.log(req.body.keyword[i]); // for debugging purpose
  }

  console.log(qarray);
}
```

Comment: I've choosen the loop solution, and I've update the answer. I'm quite new to the asynchronous functions, still have a lot to learn. Why does the _ReferenceError: Cannot access 'pushy' before initialization_ means ?  The **.then** sould not let it wait for an answer ?

Comment: @VortexSensei you don't need `.then()` and `catch()` when you await, instead wrap them into try catch

Comment: The try catch solution solved my problem, thanks a lot !